# snowflake change owner of a share from accountadmin to another role?

Tags: share, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We create many shares with accountadmin.

Now we granted 'create shares' to sysadmin, how can i change the ownership of previous shares to sysadmin without drop and recreate the share?

Comment: True, as Rajib has answered shares need to be recreated and is done for a security reason as it allows users with these roles to expose any objects they own (or on which they have the necessary privileges) to other accounts. This is particularly important to note if you are sharing data from an account that contains sensitive or proprietary data.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-privileges-shares.html

Answer (score 1):

I think currently

```
The ACCOUNTADMIN role has the privileges to create a share.

You can also grant CREATE SHARE and IMPORT SHARE to other roles, enabling the tasks to be delegated to other users in the account. For more information, see Enabling non-ACCOUNTADMIN Roles to Perform Data Sharing Tasks.
```

Also Ownership of a share cannot be transferred to another role

```
Ownership of a share, as well as the objects in the share, may be either through a direct grant to the role or inherited from a lower-level role in the role hierarchy. For more details, see Role Hierarchy and Privilege Inheritance.

Also, it’s possible for the same role to own a share and the objects in the share.
```

The only option will be to drop and recreate the share